# Android: WebView, how to go full screen and hide the title

Tags: android, webview

I want to make WebView fullscreen by hiding the topbar.

Upon research, this is supposed to work:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But adding this crashes my app upon launch. What am I doing wrong and how do you achieve this?

Comment: what does the crash say?

Answer (score 11):

Try,

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

in your **onCreate()**

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply below style in your **manifest** file

like:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"/>
```

in **style.xml**, add below style

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just follow these steps

1. Open your java file.
2. you will find onCreate method (below where it is written @override)
   It looks like this

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity {     //#1
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                //#3
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ```

Under the line and above setContentview // #3 add this line

```
       this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

3. this is the last step in the line //#1 you can see **`AppCompactActivity`** change it to **`Activity`**. It will show an error  because the  **Activity** class is not imported. So import the **Activity** class by taking your cursor between **Activity** and press **alt + enter** to import class. Alternatively manually import it just write this line in import above **`import android.app.Activity;`**

For confirmation, your new code will look like this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;


     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          }


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

No Need to do too much circus. just copy & paste it below COPY MARKED CODE in your MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // START -- copy from here
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    // END -- copy till here

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    //webView.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://app.noorcool.com/");
}
}
```

Thats it. Enjoy coding

Comment: this works for me. thanks for sharing.hope this script will be always compatible with future updates.

Answer (score 1):

This was a very simple solution for me.

Search for wherever you have some kind of ActionBar,

for me I had it in res/values/themes.xml and res/values-night/themes.xml.

In there, change any DarkActionBar or LightActionbar you have into NoActionBar.

for example, before:

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

after:

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

That's it! Worked perfectly for me.

source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/android+studio+webview+remove+title+bar

Answer (score 0):

add this your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your activity extends CompatActivity, therfore it should have a compat theme. 
If I'm right, just change your activity to extend Activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for hiding top bar..in Manifest..add this try
   <application
     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

 for webview full screen

 in XML
   <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"/>

    and in Mainactivity...do like this

   public class MainActivity extends Activity{
```